# How to fix a widget in the dashboard plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, dashboard

I am trying to adjust the plugin demoed here http://www.gxdeveloperweb.com/dashboardplugin/demo/dashboard.html to my needs.

The most urgent thing is that widgets must have parameter(in config file for example)  – widget position is "fixed" or "not fixed" on the scheme.

So how could i do that and how to make a widget not draggable?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: see here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316367/customized-jquery-ui-dashboard-plugin

Comment: Thanks! Yes i did. Basically pleased with the functionality provided and need only to be able to fix a widget in one of the column. The answer by the link says about a bit another thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add have the `items` property and only have the items that do not have the fixed class.

**Here is a fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/DUSKm/

As well as the simple code here:

**jQuery:**

```
$('#container').sortable({
    items: '.item:not(.fixed)'
});
$('#container').disableSelection();
​
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item fixed">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item">Item 4</div>
</div>​
```